Can I input a voltage of -10V to the gate?

Can I input a voltage of -10V to the gate of a P-channel FET using basic electronic components such as resistors and diodes?

I'll redraw your circuit with higher potentials at the top, to make it easier to parse:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
There isn't any node in that circuit having "absolute" potential -10V, everything here is 0V, +10V, or somewhere in between. You can't set \$V_G=-10V\$ without having another voltage source somewhere.
However, that's not a problem, because you don't control the MOSFET with \$V_G\$, you control it with \$V_{GS}\$, which is equal to:
$$ V_{GS} = V_G - V_S $$
There is a huge distinction between an "absolute" potential like \$V_G\$, and a potential difference like \$V_{GS}=V_G-V_S\$. In this case it is the potential difference \$V_G-V_S\$ that needs to be strongly negative, which can be achieved without having access to a negative absolute potential, like -10V.
For a P-channel enhancement mode MOSFET, like the one shown, when \$V_{GS} >> V_{GS(TH)}\$, the MOSFET is turned off. \$V_{GS(TH)}\$ (sometimes called just \$V_{TH}\$) is a "threshold" parameter found in the MOSFET's datasheet. Typically a P-channel MOSFET will have \$V_{GS(TH)}\approx -3V\$, very approximately. It can range from -0.5V to maybe -8V, depending on the model. It other words, to turn off a P-channel MOSFET, \$V_{GS}\$ must be significantly more positive than \$V_{GS(TH)}\$.
In the above schematic, the potential at node S (the MOSFET's source terminal) is \$V_S = +10V\$. Its gate is connected to the same node, and has the same potential, \$V_G = V_S = +10V\$. Therefore:
$$ V_{GS} = V_G - V_S = (+10V) - (+10V) = 0V $$
This satisfies the condition \$V_{GS} >> V_{GS(TH)}\$ necessary to switch the transistor off.
To switch on a P-channel MOSFET, we must satisfy the condition \$V_{GS} << V_{GS(TH)}\$. In other words, \$V_{GS}\$ must be significantly more negative than \$V_{GS(TH)}\$. In our case here, we can achieve \$V_{GS} = -10V\$ by connecting the gate (node G) to ground, 0V:

simulate this circuit
Now:
$$ V_{GS} = V_G - V_S = 0V - (+10V) = -10V $$
This is certainly more negative than \$V_{GS(TH)}\$, the MOSFET is definitely on, and lamp B1 will illuminate.

Use the other end of the supply.

